# jquery doesn't work in dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver

I have this snippet that works perfect, but when i put it on Dreamweaver it doesn't. What is missing?

```js
$('div').each( function() {
  orgText = $(this).html();
  newText = orgText.replace('(Código:','');
  $(this).html(newText);
});


$('div').each( function() {
  orgText = $(this).html();
    newText = orgText.replace(')','');
  $(this).html(newText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
(Código: 40398488494)
</div>
```

[Dreamweaver capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64cNu.png)

Any help i would appreciate, thanks

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in: `$(document).ready(function() {});`?

Comment: what is error? check console

Comment: If you mean that you're using the Dreamweaver preview window then I would strongly suggest you don't. You should always test in a browser. To solve your actual problem put your code in a document.ready handler as Carl has suggested

Comment: I´m testing in Firefox.

Comment: No console errors Wahwahwah

Comment: Thanks Carl Edwards, this was the solution

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you load the jquery in the header like that.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of initial page load, you're searching for a (then) unknown element, because the JS is firing before the HTML has been rendered in full.

You can either place the JS at the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>`, and put the `<div><small>(Código: 40398488494)</small></div>` *above*/*before* the JS, or you can (preferably) use `$(document).ready()`.

Each of the following will work:

**With $(document).ready()**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div').each( function() {
                orgText = $(this).html();
                newText = orgText.replace('(Código:','');
                $(this).html(newText);
            });
            $('div').each( function() {
                orgText = $(this).html();
                newText = orgText.replace(')','');
                $(this).html(newText);
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div><small>(Código: 40398488494)</small></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice how it doesn't matter *where* `<div><small>(Código: 40398488494)</small></div>` is because the JS will not fire until the page is *ready*.

**WITHOUT $(document).ready()**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div><small>(Código: 40398488494)</small></div>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script>
        $('div').each( function() {
            orgText = $(this).html();
            newText = orgText.replace('(Código:','');
            $(this).html(newText);
        });
        $('div').each( function() {
            orgText = $(this).html();
            newText = orgText.replace(')','');
            $(this).html(newText);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`<div><small>(Código: 40398488494)</small></div>` must come *before* your JS if you're not using `$(document).ready()`.

The first example (with `$(document).ready()` is preferable as it allows you to customize what JS fires and when.

More on [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Good explanation, i didn't know that. Thanks.